# How to find item in ArrayList filled with list of userdefined class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

`ArrayList` contains `list` of `items` of type `clsPMLookUpValue`

```
class clsPMLookUpValue
{
    public string LongValue;
    public string ShortValue;
    public string value;
}
```

I want to get `ShortValue` from `ArrayList` item which has `Value = 101202`.
In short want to get `ShortValue` by checking `Value`.
How to do that?
 Can we do that by using `lambda expression` or by other way?

Comment: Do you have to use ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, that is already there..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `ArrayList` is declared that way

```
System.Collections.ArrayList al = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
al.Add(new clsPMLookUpValue() { value = "101202", ShortValue = "ShortValue", LongValue = "LongValue" });
```

this is the way to select the `ShortValue`

```
string result = al.Cast<clsPMLookUpValue>().Where(x => x.value == "101202").Select(x => x.ShortValue).First();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
new ArrayList(listOld.Cast<clsPMLookUpValue>() .Where(i => i.value == "101202") .Select(i=>i.ShortValue).ToList());
```

Comment: new ArrayList(listOld.Cast<clsPMLookUpValue>()
                                                 .Where(i => i.value == "101202")
                                                 .Select(i=>i.ShortValue).ToList());