# Having trouble with adding a update () method to my console inventory application

Tags: c#, console, inventory

I am making a simple inventory console application.
So far I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Inventory
{
    string name;
    double cost;
    int onhand;

    public Inventory(string n, double c, int h)
    {
        name = n;
        cost = c;
        onhand = h;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return
          String.Format("{0,-10}Cost: {1,6:C}  On hand: {2}", name, cost, onhand);
    }
}

public class InventoryList
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ArrayList inv = new ArrayList();

        // Add elements to the list 
        inv.Add(new Inventory("Pliers", 5.95, 3));
        inv.Add(new Inventory("Wrenches", 8.29, 2));
        inv.Add(new Inventory("Hammers", 3.50, 4));
        inv.Add(new Inventory("Drills", 19.88, 8));

        Console.WriteLine("Inventory list:");
        foreach (Inventory i in inv)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   " + i);
        }
```

I added this code to add a new product to the list.

```
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Input New Inventory");
        Console.WriteLine("Name : ");
        string newName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Cost : ");
        double newCost = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Onhand : ");
        int newOnhand = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        inv.Add(new Inventory(newName, newCost, newOnhand));

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Inventory List:");
        foreach (Inventory i in inv)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n")
    }
}
```

I am unable to figure out how to add an `update()` method to change the stock number in the list.

My question is how do I add an update method to change the number of stock in the list while in the console window?
In console I would input the product name and the new stock number an return a new list with the updated stock number for the product.

Comment: Do you have to use an `ArrayList`? You'd have to query it with LINQ (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268186/how-to-find-item-in-arraylist-filled-with-list-of-userdefined-class) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-query-an-arraylist-with-linq)) but LINQ may be too advanced for your current level of knowledge. Perhaps a Dictionary is an easier option here, with the product name as the key and an `Inventory` object as the value.

Answer (score 0):

I aggree with Stijn's comment. A Dictionary or List would be a better solution than an ArrayList - but if you *must* use an ArrayList - you could write a function to return the index and use this to update your ArrayList:

```
    private static int GetIndex(string name, ArrayList inv)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < inv.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (((Inventory)inv[i]).Name.Equals(name))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1; 
    }
```

Then in main:

```
        var index = GetIndex("Drills", inv);
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            ((Inventory)inv[index]).StockNumber = 15; // Or whatever...
        }
```